How to prepare a NuGet package containing native dlls for both x86 and x64 and the respective .NET wrapper?
After doing my research I have come up with a solution, but it has some minor problems which I want to resolve.
The NuGet package consists of a single C# project:
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/3.0.44">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472</TargetFrameworks>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <ExtrasBuildEachRuntimeIdentifier>true</ExtrasBuildEachRuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <NoWarn>NU5131</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="runtimes/**/*.*" Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes" />
    <None Include="*.targets" Pack="true" PackagePath="build" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="AddReferenceAssemblies" BeforeTargets="GenerateNuspec">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_PackageFiles Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)net472\win-x86\ref\MyAssembly.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="ref/net472" BuildAction="None" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>

The targets file is important, it is responsible to copy the native dlls to the target app's bin directory:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x64' or '$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x86' ">
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\runtimes\win-$(PlatformTarget)\native\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

The Nuget package delivers a native dll MyNativeLib.dll and the respective .NET wrapper MyAssembly.dll. Here is the resulting NuGet package layout in the NuGet cache directory  ~/.nuget/packages:
C:.
│   .nupkg.metadata
│   MyNuGetPackage.1.0.24281.1.nupkg
│   MyNuGetPackage.1.0.24281.1.nupkg.sha512
│   MyNuGetPackage.nuspec
│
├───build
│       MyNuGetPackage.targets
│
├───ref
│   └───net472
│           MyAssembly.dll
│
└───runtimes
    ├───win-x64
    │   ├───lib
    │   │   └───net472
    │   │           MyAssembly.dll
    │   │           MyAssembly.pdb
    │   │
    │   └───native
    │           MyNativeLib.dll
    │
    └───win-x86
        ├───lib
        │   └───net472
        │           MyAssembly.dll
        │           MyAssembly.pdb
        │
        └───native
                MyNativeLib.dll

The application using it just needs to specify either PlatformTarget=x86 or PlatformTarget=x64 and reference the NuGet package.
Here is how it looks like:
32 bits
C:\Test> del -r bin,obj -Force
C:\Test> dotnet build /p:PlatformTarget=x86 /v:q

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.77

Workload updates are available. Run `dotnet workload list` for more information.
C:\Test> &$dumpbin /headers bin\Debug\net472\MyNativeLib.dll | sls machine

             14C machine (x86)
                   32 bit word machine

C:\Test> &$dumpbin /headers bin\Debug\net472\MyAssembly.dll | sls machine

             14C machine (x86)
                   32 bit word machine

C:\Test>

64 bits
C:\Test> del -r bin,obj -Force
C:\Test> dotnet build /p:PlatformTarget=x64 /v:q

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.26

Workload updates are available. Run `dotnet workload list` for more information.
C:\Test> &$dumpbin /headers bin\Debug\net472\MyNativeLib.dll | sls machine

            8664 machine (x64)

C:\Test> &$dumpbin /headers bin\Debug\net472\MyAssembly.dll | sls machine

            8664 machine (x64)

C:\Test>

My problem is that the AddReferenceAssemblies target mentions the path $(IntermediateOutputPath)net472\win-x86\ref\MyAssembly.dll, where I am forced to hard code the reference assembly runtime identifier - either win-x86 or win-x64.
That means that when compiling the target application for PlatformTarget = x64 I get an annoying warning:
C:\Test> del -r bin,obj -Force
C:\Test> dotnet build /p:PlatformTarget=x64
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Test\Test.csproj (in 516 ms).
CSC : warning CS8012: Referenced assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.24281.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' targets a different processor. [C:\Test\Test.csproj]
  Test -> C:\Test\bin\Debug\net472\Test.exe

Build succeeded.

CSC : warning CS8012: Referenced assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.24281.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' targets a different processor. [C:\Test\Test.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.32

Workload updates are available. Run `dotnet workload list` for more information.
C:\Test>

How can I get rid of this warning without explicitly suppressing it?

When I copy your csproj, but modify it to use Microsoft.NET.Sdk instead of MSBuild.Sdk.Extras, dotnet build will create the "AnyCPU" (or ridless) build, including ref assembly. This will avoid the CS8012.  However, it doesn't automatically build all the RID specific assets.  You can get around this by using something like https://github.com/baronfel/sdk-container-demo/blob/main/src%2Fsdk-container-demo%2Fsdk-container-demo.csproj#L40, or just having your CI script have two dotnet build -r ??? steps before packing, but that will make local building and testing harder

Also, I recommend against both using files in NuGet's runtimes/ convention based directory, in addition to your own props/targets files. In scenarios when the .NET SDK will automatically copy the RID specific files, your targets might conflict with them and cause unexpected problems. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/native-files-in-net-packages

Could you arrange your comments as the answer so that I could credit you? Please, bear in mind that not only do I need to build the 2 rids, but I also need to pack them into the same NuGet package using the dotnet pack command. I do not want to have 2 NuGet packages.,
